# Need help understand how Strings work in my method

Tags: string, methods

I am trying to understand how this convertingStringToInt method works. I am reading a file, storing the values in an array and am to pass those values to the method to be converted. In the parameters of convertingStringToInt, I have (String number) I don't get where the String "number" is getting its values. So I am passing in a string called numbers, but how is that newly created String associated with any of the values in my file...?!?

I am trying to understand the cause all the return numbers are the error code -460 except the last digit in the file. So the String numbers is associated with the file somehow I just don't get how...

```
public static void read_file()
{
    try {
        File file = new File("randomNumbers.txt"); 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        int amountOfNumbersInFile = convertingStringToInt(scan.nextLine()); // read the first line which is 100 to set array size
        global_numbers = new int[amountOfNumbersInFile]; // set the array size equal to the first line read which is 100
        for (int index = 0; index < amountOfNumbersInFile; index++) 
        {
           String line = scan.nextLine(); 
           global_numbers [index] = convertingStringToInt(line); 
        }       
    } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
public static int convertingStringToInt(String numbers) //what does string "number" equal? why/where is it declared?
{  
    String numbers = scan.nextInt(); 
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(numbers);
    } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
        return -460;
    }         
}
```

I have global_numbers declared as a global variable.

Comment: Remove the line `String line = scan.nextLine();` **or** `String numbers = scan.nextInt();`,  as you already send the String numbers in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

so the first thing u need understand is what u have in your txt file 
if in this file you have only number is ok use stringToInt 
but if you have words this never work properly

Comment: Yes all I have are ints in my text file

Comment: so first make trim() on you strings to make sure you don't have empty space  and is essential for this work properly use serializable class

Comment: global_numbers [index] = Integer.parseInt(line);